# How to put spaces in variable names?

Tags: c++, variables, mql5

I want to learn how to add spaces in variable names.

I know that a lot languages prevent me from doing this, but I believe that there is a trick to do this because I saw someone did it in **`MQL5`**

A <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal</kbd> allows to show a UI-Dialogue Panel for MMI-assisted setting values for `input` and `extern` variables declared in { `Expert Advisor` | `Technical Indicator` | `Script` } code, during a code-execution launch.

( Ref. a picture below ):  [image: A MetaTrader Termina Dialogue Panel for setting values for <code>input</code> and <code>extern</code> variables on { Expert Advisor | Technical Indicator | Script } code-execution launch].

Comment: why (and what's wrong with using underscores for that purpose)?

Comment: you_can_do_no_such_thing.

Comment: What you're seeing in mql5 isn't the name a C++ variable. I would guess that it's the "name" property of a type that represents mql5's own "variables".

Comment: I inlined your picture (you cannot do that yet I believe). I also removed some chit-chat and cleaned up the wording of your post.

Comment: @BaummitAugen a wonderfull profile message, Baum

Answer (score 2):

In `C++` you can't put spaces in variable names but you can get what you want using a [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

For example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> vars;

    vars["Time Frame"] = "15 minutes";
    vars["Indicator Period"] = "16";
    // ... etc

}
```

The [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is an *associative container* that maps one `std::string` onto another.

Depending on how you intend to use the *map* you may also want to consider using an [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which should have higher performance but will not keep the keys sorted and may have a higher memory usage.

Comment: unordered_map is more efficient in this case

Comment: @Brahim I'd say "more scalable"

Comment: Can you explain? I meant more efficient in term of performance.

Comment: @Brahim There's no guarantee without knowing the implementation of std::hash<std::string> that std::unordered_map is more efficient than std::map for a certain X amount of strings.
Maybe the std::hash<std::string> is actually very long to compute and that it would be faster to compare for equality a couple more times.
But with more and more keys, the hash is usually faster, yes. Hence "more scalable".

Comment: @Brahim: That's a dangerous sweeping generalisation. There is no container that is universally "more efficient" than some other container. Each has pros and cons for distinct use cases. That's why we have more than one choice in the first place, after all...

Comment: @Brahim I have added a note regarding `std::unordered_map` so people can investigate both options.

Comment: @KABoissonneault and Lightness Thanks for the comment. What Imeant is that operations in tree-like maps is logarithmic (of number of nodes in the tree) while hash tables operations are done in constant time (of the number of elements in the table). But in practical point of view you are both right

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to be evil you can sometimes use the left-to-right mark, [U+200E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) which looks like a regular space but is generally not considered whitespace. Different languages and/or specific platforms may behave differently.

This trick [seems to work in C#](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/02/17/spaces-in-identifier-names-in-c/) and apparently you can do [similar things in ruby](http://www.rubyinside.com/the-split-is-not-enough-whitespace-shenigans-for-rubyists-5980.html).

I tried this using g++ and luckily for everyone's sanity it is not allowed:

```
foo.cc:5:10: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers
    int a<U+200E> b = 3;
```

Please don't do this outside of pranks and April fool's day jokes.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know, there isn't any option to add spaces to variables name.

Comment: how explain the screen shot ?

Comment: @TheXLearner It could be that the variable viewer automatically puts a space before Capital letters in CamelCase names.
I know the Unreal Engine does that for blueprints

Comment: @KABoissonneault , didn't catch it , I'am a newbie programmer :)

Comment: @KABoissonneault: It's obviously not that if you look at some of the other "variable names" in the screenshot

Comment: @TheXLearner: The screenshot has literally nothing to do with C++ variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with using spaces in names (whether filenames, variable names or something else) is that you need to have some other mechanism for determining what is part of this name and what is part of the next section of code. Your sample looks like a form, so that has it's own formatting and structure.

SQL does allow you to "quote" variable names with either `[name with space]` or with backticks `` `name with space` ``.

Most other languages do not allow spaces in variable names, because any whitedspace is considered a separator for different lexical unit [different name/word/variable]. There is no way you can change this, as it would alter the meaning of "normal code". Most languages do allow/use `_` as a "space in names" character.

Of course, if you have "variables" that are your own construct, read from for example a database or file, you can use your own syntax, and use for example `std::map<std::string, sometype>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string, sometype>` to connect the string from your data to the corresponding value.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces (white space) are used in C++ to isolate keywords and variable names, thus they cannot exist in a variable name or the compiler will treat the text as multiple identifiers.

Example - valid:  `static const unsigned int my_variable = 6U;`

If there is a space between `my` and `variable` how does the compiler know which is the variable name?  If there are two variables here, it doesn't make sense.

Also, as you can see, there may be more than one keyword in a statement.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution .
In Mql5 , when you add a comment next to the variable name , it will appear instead of the variable name . 
See this image : http://prntscr.com/79vaae

Comment: The StackOverflow purity dictates to carefully separate what is a solution and what is not. **Yes, `MQL4/MQL5` syntactical side-effect allows to display `// a remark text with spaces` in a `GUI_DialoguePANEL` _BUT_DO_NOTICE_ that it does _NOT_ answer the given qeustion _AND_ it does _NOT_ prove a possibility to "inject" space(s) into any variable name** ( which is documented as principally ruled-out as a forbidden feature for the MetaLang syntax parser/compiler ). **Welcome TheXLearner to the world of StackOverflow and both enjoy and contribute to the immense knowledge base here**